# Changing the System Time in Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory, systemtime

I would like to use my local time as the System Time in Google Colab, but I believe by default it is set to UTC time as indicated here:
[Current Date Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76gMk.png)

How am I able to change the system time to my local time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how to do it. For me, I live in Asia/Bangkok

```
!rm /etc/localtime
!ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Bangkok /etc/localtime
!date
```

Now I get `Tue Apr 30 20:12:30 +07 2019`. You can see the list of timezones by

```
!ls -al /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

And go into sub-directories for each group. (or simply search google)

Comment: It seems that the Colab runtime does not notice the timezone change until the runtime is restarted, as can be seen by evaluating `time.localtime(time.time())`

Comment: To anonymous user, here is list of [IANA Timezone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#List)